# How would the financial situation be, if a person not only lives quite long, but also has Alzheimer's disease?

Tags: united-states, retirement, annuity

If we live to 85, and set aside some money to live to 85, that's all good. But what might worry us, is what if we live to 95 or 105, and therefore need more money to live on, and also, with things possibly doubling in prices after 15 years or 18 years.

Then not only do we need money, plus there is also a possibility of Alzheimer's disease. In that case, what could we do?  Does the government have some help program, or can the person buy some kind of annuity, which would provide income of, say US$2000 per month, and would increase accordingly related to inflation?

Comment: Not a happy thought, but those problems probably offset each other somewhat. Alzheimer;s likely reduces your life expectancy dramatically.

Comment: While it's true that Alzheimer's likely reduces your life expectancy, the average life expectancy is about 10 years with an upper limit in the 20 year area.  So if the OP is diagnosed in his early 80's, having sufficient money would still be problematic.

Comment: There's medicaid for when you have very little resources left.

Comment: Yes, there's  Medicaid but it's not a good position to end up at.

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues here.  The first is that you may run out of money if you live past the age of 85 and the second is that there's the possibility of Alzheimer's disease in which case you're going to need even more money because there will likely to be a need for caregivers.

There are a variety of annuities that address the first issue.  I'll take a pass on their pros and cons other than to say that they will pay a person until the person passes away.  If the person lives long enough, he or she gets into the insurance company's pocket.

For the second issue, there's long term care insurance.  I don't know what's out there now but when I purchased mine, it included a 5% annual COLA.  Since I took a 10-pay policy, it's fully paid off and they can never dun me for another penny of premium increase as they can those with annual payment policies.  My daily coverage is now about 130% more than the starting amount.

In both cases, the younger you are when you start, the better the result when you are older.